# Toolbar in Xamarin Android not showing icons

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-toolbar

I'm trying to create a toolbar to save items in my application. But my toolbar is not showing properly.

It is showing like this [image]
I want to display like this 
 [image]

In my Fragment

```
    public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_RefuelingToolbar, menu);
    }
```

menu_RefuelingToolbar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          tools:context=".RefuelingFragment">
          <item android:id="@+id/button_Save"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp"
                android:showAsAction="always"
                android:title="Settings" />
    </menu>
```

Comment: What's the type of your Activity, Activity or AppCompatActivity?

Comment: It is a fragment. Not an Activity.

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Please refer my project: https://github.com/Chindara/XamarinAndroidNavigationDrawer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity` like this :

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity {...}//instead of Activity
```

In this case, the toolbar cant showing picture, the reason is that :

> When using the appcompat library, menu resources should refer to the showAsAction in the app: namespace, not the android: namespace.
>   Similarly, when not using the appcompat library, you should be using the android:showAsAction attribute.

I think the problem is that you are mixing Framework `Activity` and `AppCompat` menu.

You should use `AppCompatActivity` with `AppCompat Action bar` and `app:showAsAction`; or Activity with `android:showAsAction`.

**EDIT** : Modify your code in `menu_MGradeToolbar.xml` like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   >
<item android:id="@+id/button_MGradeSave"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Save" />
</menu>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LipPm.png) is the result.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Please refer my project: https://github.com/Chindara/XamarinAndroidNavigationDrawer

Comment: Thanks a lot. It Works.I have updated my GitHub project with the solution.